# How to become better at figuring out and telling companies what motivations they want to hear in interviews?

Tags: interviewing

So I got through all the tech eval stages and this one company but after all that leetcode still got rejected.

I contacted a friend in HR there and asked for my notes and it turns out that they thought my goals and motivations were misaligned. Basically I demonstrated an interest in product development and they wanted infrastructure people. Passed the leetcode and got screwed over in team matching due to a lack of fit on that.

How do you figure out what a company wants to hear for workplace values, approaches to tasks, and generate appropriate answers? I don't need to be motivated at work.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I will happily tell them a different goal to get a job at this tier of company. My goals are my own problem.

Comment: Was it clear what the role expected when you applied? I think people will have different answers if your question is "how to disguise my intentions to pass an interview for a job I don't actually want" versus "how to gauge company culture during an interview"

Comment: @HerexTheDog - while there is nothing wrong with crafting your answers to obtain a job (provided you are not lying about things) an experienced interviewer can often tell the difference between someone who is expressing genuine interest from someone who isnt.

Comment: You just ask them. There is no magic trick. I have no reason to suspect a headhunter is going to have a better idea than you.

Comment: Why would you want to work at a company that doesn't align with your personal values/goals?  Sounds like a recipe for being miserable and ultimately leaving the company.

Comment: "I don't need to be motivated at work." <- _You_ might not need to be, but if I'm hiring I want people that are. Sounds like the interview process is going a good job.

Comment: Better to just be honest about what you want. If you want to do product development, you aren't going to be happy in a job demanding infrastructure work and will be looking for a new job soon anyway.

Comment: @sf02 good brand name. I'm willing to do uninteresting stuff for a year to get the brand name.

Comment: @PhilipKendall yes, but that is not in my interest. I am asking how to look after my interests.

Comment: @SethR that is fine for me. Stick around for a year or so and get a good brand name on the resume.

Comment: @HerexTheDog Brand names do not necessarily help you. If you managed to get FAANG all on your resume, people will ask why you left any of those amazing high paying companies. The name is not impressive by itself; you have to actually have done something. People can tell almost immediately what you're trying to do and won't hire you, regardless of your former employer's prestige.

Comment: @HerexTheDog If you think you can even be a passable developer while being unmotivated, I got news for you; they'll know within months, if not weeks, and you'll tank your career. Software Development is a highly creative process, and you can't excel at things you do not like.

Comment: The good old advice of "do your research" - read the company website, read the job description, read Glassdoor, etc. And learn how to read between the lines and identify things that would be a red flag for you or that will trigger a red flag in your resume

Answer (score 1):

> How do you figure out what a company wants to hear for workplace
> values, approaches to tasks, and generate appropriate answers? I don't
> need to be motivated at work.

Read through their website to notice clues regarding their values and approaches to tasks. Ask relevant questions during interviews and listen carefully to the tone and content of the answers. If you have someone in your professional network that knows the company, talk with them. Or go through an independent headhunter. They can often tell you what the company wants to hear.

Then you can "tune your answer" accordingly.

Maybe the company won't detect your lack of honesty in your answers, or maybe they won't actually care. And maybe you'll get the job that way. And maybe you'll do well at something you aren't motivated to do.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't need to be motivated at work.

Sure, you don't.

But what if they hire you to be a glorified janitor, and then an equivalent FAANG employer headhunts you to do R&D on a cool new product?

Will you jump at the new opportunity? Of course, you would.

If you've worked on cool projects in the past, it's likely that you'll jump at the chance to work on cool projects in the future as soon as you have the leverage to do so.

> How do you figure out what a company wants to hear for workplace values, approaches to tasks...

You do your research, of course, but you also look for insider information.

1. Use your professional network. Network with people. Ask for introductions. Don't be afraid to ask for help. Do informational interviews. Go to meetups. Use LinkedIn. Etc.
2. Use good 3rd party recruiters (that colleagues highly recommend). Not all 3rd party recruiters are good, in fact, the barrier to entry is so low, most 3rd party recruiters are absolutely awful. But if you can find a good 3rd party recruiter that comes highly recommended, that person can be worth their weight in gold. If they do their job well, that means they've debriefed hundreds of candidates and potential employers after their interviews, and they'll be able to use those experiences and those debriefing sessions to steer you in the right direction.

> How do you figure out what a company wants to hear for workplace
> values, approaches to tasks, **and generate appropriate answers?**

Sure, you can do that, and you should do that to a certain degree. But at the same time, you should really be proactive about finding the right job for yourself. In other words, don't just apply to companies because they happen to have a job opening.

Explore the [hidden job market](https://www.thebalancecareers.com/what-is-the-hidden-job-market-2062004) as well. Look for jobs in companies and departments that really want to work in, even if they don't have job opening for your skills. Do informational interviews with people that you would really like to work with. Many of the best jobs get snapped up before they even get advertised.

And don't get me wrong, I'm not saying you shouldn't apply to job postings when you see them. I'm not saying that at all. I'm saying you should try every strategy at your disposal, whether it involves going after the open job market or the hidden one.

With that said, if you have an inside line on a new job, always try using the inside line before trying to use the front door (or before using an external recruiter). Internal referrals are always better, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Reading through the job requirement is your most reliable source of information. You must try to deduct that information to try align the vision and expectation. Of course you cannot always be sure on this.

The safest way to do this is to say what is your ideal state for the job. For example: "I really like to design things myself, develop products in-house because by doing so I feel more impactful rather than trying to outsource everything. But, I realize that sometimes we're short in time and manpower, so being the man that handle all the third party for this product development will also suits me". **That is an example of trying to go for a *safe* answer by saying that you are flexible while also expressing what is your interest.**

However, the safest answer is always trying to suit the job requirement and showing that you have full interest to the job just the way it is. But I don't suggest you doing this as it might hurt you in the future, because you're trying to squeeze in environment that you don't really like.

But, for the purpose of avoiding miscommunication in your case, I think mentioning you are flexible is the way to go.